# Activating Quick Look Using The Trackpad In OS X?

Tags: macos, trackpad, quicklook

Quick Look is very useful when wanting to preview documents and files without opening them in separate applications.

I know that you can trigger Quick Look by highlighting a file in Finder and pressing the spacebar.

Can it be activated using the trackpad on my Macbook Pro instead ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to **System Preferences > Trackpad > Point & Click** and enable the **"Look up"** checkbox. You will then be able to do a `Quick Look` with a three finger tap on the trackpad.

See:
[How to Activate OS X’s Quick Look Using Your Mac’s Trackpad - August 30, 2013 11:46 AM](http://www.tekrevue.com/tip/activate-os-xs-quick-look-using-macs-trackpad/)